# Django: Send email with Xlsxwriter Excel attachment

Tags: python, django, email-attachments

I want to send an Excel file that I have written with Xlsxwriter. The Excel file contains information I have collected from Models. The Excel file is working (tried it with HttpResponse). But I can't send it as an email attachment.

```
workbook.close()
body = "Some text here"
message = EmailMessage("Heading", body, "from@email.com", ['to@email.com'])
message.attach(workbook)
message.send()
```

If I put try except around message.attach(workbook), I get the email but there's no attachment.

Comment: Can you please include details of the exception produced when you try to attach the file?

Comment: Assert content is not None. Assertion Error.

Comment: Finally figured it out! I used message.attach_file('filename.xlsx') and it worked.